# Environment variables not being picked up in my CircleCI gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, circleci

Locally I am using a gradle.properties file to store some secrets needed for my build. This works just fine. I was reading the Gradle docs and it would seem that environment variables can be swapped out and used in the same way. [Here are the relevant docs I was reading.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html?_ga=2.69732880.1064790866.1523512513-1314005359.1522804652#build_environment)

However when I set the env vars in my CI server (CircleCI), they don't seem to get picked up.

This is that the pertinent block of my build.gradle file looks like

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

I have set the env vars with the exact same names, and when I do a `printenv` on the build server I can see them just fine.

But if I run the build, I get an error about not having the key file. And if I add an else statement to the above code and `println` a "No Property" log message, I indeed see that Gradle does not thing that property exists.

Ideas?